# I want to use Android KeyChain to store public key and private key

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to store private key in android KeyChain.  I write code to store key already. But I don't understand when uninstall app and clear app key lost or not. I want to store key in KeyChain when clear app or uninstall key still have.

```
try {
        Intent intent = KeyChain.createInstallIntent();
        intent.putExtra("PKEY", privateKey);
        intent.putExtra("KEY", publicKey);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Log.w("MainActivity", "could not store key pair: " + e);
    }
```

- Result debug code:
  [picture debug result from KeyChain.createInstallIntent();](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKAxY.png)

How can I retrieve private key from KeyChain.createInstallIntent()?

Answer (score -1):

Intent stores data for only for some limited time.If you want to store key value data permanently I suggest to use Json Api .You have to create json API using PHP &  manage your data by calling APi when you need in your android App.

Comment: To store in server api, I can do. but the purpose is keeping store on device only. So we have any solution to store our own private key on keychain android?

Comment: Yes, You can use shared preference in Android. Using it you can store the private key with the help of key and value pair. The below link helps you to implement shared preference in android.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm